# Bluemixアプリケーション開始失敗の原因調査方法

Tags: node.js, bluemix

node.jsアプリケーションのデプロイが失敗する原因を調べています。
ログを確認しようとBluemixのダッシュボードのメニューでファイルとログを選択すると、アプリケーションが開始されていないため、使用可能なファイルもログもありません。という警告が出ます。アプリケーションの開始ができないとファイルシステムにアクセスできないからログが見られないということだと思いますが、開始が失敗する原因を調べるにはどうしたらいいのですか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Foundry CLIで `cf logs <アプリ名> --recent` コマンドを使うというのが基本です。
IBM Bluemix DevOps Servicesを使用しているのであれば、Web UIからログを参照したり、デバッガーを使用したりすることも可能です。

詳細は下記URLを参照してください。
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/index-gentopic2.html
https://hub.jazz.net/tutorials/livesync/